# How come we can change a final list's value at an index in dart but not a final variable of other types?

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

For example when we assign a final String value to a variable:

```
final String name = "john";
name = "patrick" //error: the final variable name can only be set once
```

But we can change the value at an index

```
final List<String> listOfNames = ["bob", "steve", "john"];
liftOfNames[2] = "patrick"; //this is allowed
listOfNames = ["jhonny", "jim", "jack"]; //this isn't allowed(reassigning)
```

so re-assigning a final variable is not allowed but changing a final list's value at an index is allowed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Exactly. There is no option  (in Dart, languages like C++ can do that) to mark a method as changing an instance or not. So there is no syntactical difference between calling `list.length` and `list.clear()` or even `list.length` and `list.length = 5`. The dart compiler cannot distinguish whether that is a *mutating* call.

So marking something as `final` will indeed only protect it from reassignment. In your example the list variable can never be assigned another list. It can be manipulated to hold different values, but it will always be the same instance.